# Is it possible to center-align a header but left-align a subtitle to the left side of the header, preferably without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can one accomplish the following, preferably without JavaScript.

```
|                                                                               |
|                 h1. Perfectly Centered Bold, Large Font Title                 |
|                 h4. with small byline left-aligned                            |
|                                                                               |
|  p. Regular text left-aligned in nice paragraphs. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
|  consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pretium leo id venenatis lobortis.     |
|  Mauris imperdiet luctus leo nec malesuada. Morbi nisl dolor, faucibus ut     |
|  condimentum nec, sollicitudin at dolor.                                      |
|                                                                               |
```

I haven't tried yet, but I expect I could determine the left of the `h1` element and use JavaScript to manually position the `h4`.  But I'd like to see if there's a more elegant solution first.

Comment: Updated accpeted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Rob Adams was suggesting.

http://jsfiddle.net/wUsg9/5/

**CSS**

```css
.heading {
     left: 50%;
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
}
.heading h1,
.heading h4 {
     right: 50%;
     position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="heading">
     <h1>Top Heading</h1>
     <h4>Sub Heading</h4>
</div>
```

They key to this working properly is `floating` the `.header` DIV or setting it to `inline-block` so it doesn't take up more space than it needs to.  We push it left 50% of the screen and then pull it back to the right 50% of that.

Comment: This is not valid html, and should not be recommended. div tags do not belong inside of heading tags.

Comment: I said it was ugly.  He could get rid of the `h1` altogether but then it would be less semantic.

Comment: @RobAdams I updated my answer I think it will be more to your liking.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Valid html helps me get out of bed in the morning.

Comment: Yeah.  I kind of goofed that one.  I should have been more awake on that one.  Thanks for keeping me on my toes!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap h1 and h4 in a div, and center that div.